# Java 8 stream aggregate a map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Im trying to do something seemingly straighforward but with no luck so far. I have a list of **Map**, they come from a bunch of CompletableFutures in parallel, the result then has to be joined. Since the key in the map is unique, In need to merge the values and produce a new map of unique keys associated with the combined list of SomeType. For example:

Map1:
key1 : Sometype1
key2 : Sometype2

Map2
key1 : Sometype3
key2 : Sometype4

Desired final result:
Map3:
key1 : Sometype, Sometype3
key2 : Sometype2, Sometype4

I tried using groupBy and other methods, but it seems most of them assume working with a List and not a Map to begin with so I wasn't able to find a straightforward way to do it.

So far I have something like:

```
 Map<String, List<Sometype>> volPercent = waitGroup.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .flatMap((e) -> e.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy());
```

The part I'm not sure is what needs to go in the grouping by part. I tried Map.Entry::getKey, but it doesn't compile:

```
Error:(69, 25) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: com.Sometype
lower bounds: java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,com.Sometype>
```

Comment: Please construct a small runnable example of your problem, it is difficult to solve with just the stream row of code.

Comment: The upstream `CompletableFuture` stuff is a bit of a distraction. It would be good for future questions to start off with somewhat more explicit inputs. But I think I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll assume that you're starting with a stream of maps:

```
Stream<Map<String, Sometype>> input = ... ;
```

You got pretty far with the flatmapping and collecting. However, the code you tried,

```
    input.flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey));
```

gives you a map whose keys are `String` and whose values are a list of map *entries*, specifically `List<Map.Entry<String,Sometype>>`, not a `List<Sometype>` as you wanted. What you have to do is use the "downstream" feature of collectors after you've grouped them by key. You want to take each `Map.Entry` and extract (map) it to its value, which is `Sometype`. This is done with a `mapping` collector.

Now you potentially have several instances of `Sometype` for each key, so you need to collect them into a list. This is done using *another* downstream collector, which collects them into a list. This is done using the familiar `toList()` collector.

The final code looks like this:

```
Map<String, List<Sometype>> result =
    input.flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
         .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                             mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                     toList())));
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your initial attempt (as I understand it)

```
Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey)
```

collects to a `Map<K, List<Map.Entry<K, V>>>`.

After the `flatMap`, you have a `Stream<Map.Entry<K, V>>` whose elements `groupingBy` maps to `K`.

But you want a `Map<K, List<V>>` so you need to use the [`groupingBy` that takes a downstream collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-), not just a classifier, so you can also map `Map.Entry<K, V>` to `V`.

Something like

```
Collectors.groupingBy(
    Map.Entry::getKey,
    Collectors.mapping(
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        Collectors.toList()
    )
)
```